# How to save .htm file without show save dialog

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to open a file from webbrowser in vb.net that shown after i click the button ( onclick function ) , unfortunately save dialog shown up and i cant open file ( .htm )  in webbrowser directly without manual click on save or open .  here's my code :

Dim linkss As HtmlElementCollection

```
    linkss = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each link As HtmlElement In linkss
        If link.GetAttribute("className") = "TopIcon MwIcon MwExcel" Then
            link.InvokeMember("Click")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Could you not use the link attribute 'href' to download the file? or is there some js preventing this and this is why you invoke the click method?

Comment: @Pure does not have any href . save dialog appear after click link ( onclick function ) . its export link and export some .htm file .

Comment: It might be handy to see the html on the link you are invoking the click function. Also I guess you are not able to edit the html?